# C styling: why assign variables with only one space?

Tags: c, coding-style

My professor writes his C variable assignments like this:

```
int a= 10;

/*or*/
double t;
t= 0.5;
```

instead of

```
int a = 10;

/*or*/
double t;
t = 0.5;
```

He encouraged his students to do the same and mentioned that there was a specific reason as to why he does that, but never explained it. 
Is it a preprocessing thing? I see no particular reason why writing it without the first space is better.

Comment: *"but never explained it"* Don't hold your breath.

Comment: There is no real benefit at all. The only _possible_ benefit I see is that this will annoy every single perfectionist programmer, because it is irritatingly asymmetrical.

Comment: that is exactly what i thought! the lack of symmetry really gets to me.

Comment: He just told you to _believe him_. Just like religion. Which is what coding-style really is...

Comment: Well, it is just as well I don't get to review the professor's code; I would fix it so it has symmetric spacing every time.  I don't believe there's a readability advantage to the professor's notation — indeed, I think it makes it harder to read.

Comment: Please ask your professor to post an answer to this question.

Comment: When you get to a workplace or collaborate on an open source project, you will notice that different projects / workspaces have different styling requirements. Keeping these style requirements (even if they're ugly) is super important, or it becomes increasingly difficult to push changes and updates (imagine the git diff output).

Comment: teachers often act as full experienced programmers, but they aren't.  Ask him to explain and, as @paddy commented above, ask him to post a reasoning for his lack of symmetry, because for more than 40 years of C programming this is the first time I see something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can code in any styles. But you should adhere with K&R style i.e. a = 1; It will improve readability when working with you colleagues.

Answer (score 2):

It matters not at all. In fact,

```
    int
 a
 ;;;;;

    a
 =
    5
       ;
```

is just as functional, just utterly unreadable.

Pick a style and stick with it. (Don't use this style)

Answer (score 1):

Write code like you would write a book or a song.
Find YOUR style and use it —  and STICK TO IT!

```
a=1;
a= 1;
a =1;
a = 1;
```

Those should all work the same.

Comment: This a=1; is a student style. These a= 1;
a =1; look like the writer was absentminded. And only this a = 1; has a good impression.:)